# String to Hex List in Python

Tags: python

I have an input string (ex: "hello") and want to convert it to a list of hex bytes.

Ex: "hello" in hex is 68656c6c6f and I am trying to create [0x68, 0x65, 0x6c, 0x6c, 0x6f].

What is the best way to do this in Python?

Answer (score 3):

Use `ord` with `hex`:

```
[hex(ord(i)) for i in "hello"]
```

Output:

```
['0x68', '0x65', '0x6c', '0x6c', '0x6f']
```

Comment: How would I make this a list of hex types? The output for [hex(ord(i)) for i in "hello"] is a list of strings.